# When does $\lfloor\sqrt{x^2 + n}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + n}\rfloor$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Call $x \in[\sqrt{n},n/2] \cap \Bbb{Z} $ a critical point if the following holds

$$\left \lfloor\sqrt{x^2 + n}\right\rfloor = 
  \left \lfloor\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + n} \right \rfloor$$

It appears that mostly this does not happen. For most of the time you have:

$$\left\lfloor\sqrt{x^2 + n}\right\rfloor 
  = 1 + \left\lfloor\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + n}\right\rfloor$$

I can write some simple code to run through every $x$ from $\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil$ to $n/2$ and just check to see when the equality holds but that is an $O(n)$ calculation and I'm sure there must be a faster way to do this.

I tried to massage the equation and remove the floor functions by being careful and such, but I keep winding up with trivial identities instead of things that will actually help me calculate the critical points.

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Your requirement that $x \in[\sqrt{n},n/2]$ implies that $n \ge 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that the values you want to consider are $$x=\bigg\lfloor \frac {n}{2k} - \frac{k}{2} +1 \bigg\rfloor$$ for positive integers $k$, in which case $\lfloor \sqrt{x^2+n}\rfloor =\lfloor \sqrt{(x-1)^2+n}\rfloor = x + k-1$,

although

- for odd $n$ this is greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ when $k=1$
- given $n$, this is less than $\sqrt{n}$ for large $k$: for example when $n=50$ and $k \ge 3$, though curiously when $n=49$ or $51$ only for $k \ge 4$

Comment: This appears to be correct for many values of $n$ that I can check. I don't know how you find results like these. Can you share a method or reference?

Comment: @amcalde: I looked at the solutions for $1 \le n \le 1000$ and then looked for patterns

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: There can be multiple solutions $x$ for any particular $n$ but they are all of the form stated when $k$ is a positive integer.  For example when $n=50$ there are solutions when $k=1$ or $k=2$ making $x= \bigg\lfloor \dfrac {50}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2} +1 \bigg\rfloor = 25$ or $x= \bigg\lfloor \dfrac {50}{4} - \dfrac{2}{2} +1 \bigg\rfloor = 12$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \left\lfloor\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + n}\right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor\sqrt{x^2 + n}\right\rfloor$$

Let 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + n} = \sqrt{x^2+n - (2x-1)}$$

$$g(x) = \sqrt{x^2+n}$$

The condition $x \in[\sqrt{n},n/2] \cap \Bbb{Z}$ implies that 
$n \in \{4,5,6,\dots\}$ where I'm assuming that you mean for $n$ to be an integer.

it follows that $0 < f(x) < g(x)$ and both functions are strictly increasing.

Suppose that $x_N^\phantom{2} \in[\sqrt{n},n/2]\cap \Bbb{Z}$ and
$f(x_N^\phantom{2})=N\in \Bbb Z$, for some integer, $N \ge 4$.
Then 
$x_N^\phantom{2} = 1 + \sqrt{N^2-n}$. Hence
\begin{align}
   g(x_N^\phantom{X}) &= \sqrt{(1 + \sqrt{N^2-n})^2+n} \\
        &= \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{N^2-n} + N^2-n+n} \\
        &= \sqrt{1 + 2\sqrt{N^2-n} + N^2} \\
        &\lt \sqrt{1 + 2N + N^2} \\
        &= N+1
\end{align}

It follows that

$$ N = \left\lfloor\sqrt{(x_N^\phantom{X}-1)^2 + n}\right\rfloor
 = \left\lfloor\sqrt{x_N^2 + n}\right\rfloor$$

So the solution set is the set of all $x \in[\sqrt{n},n/2] \cap \Bbb{Z}$ such that 
$\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + n}$ is an integer.